# parse problem array in array php+javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to change data in highcharts value with ajax posting method. I can do it but when i want to set drilldown data using ajax, i have some problem with return data.

ajax response for data is;

```
$datas["dataDrill"] =
    [
        [
            "name"  => "instagram",
            "id"    => "instagram",
            "data"  =>
            [
                "cats1" => 4,
                "cats2" => 5,
                "cats3" => 6,
            ]
        ],
        [
            "name"  => "google",
            "id"    => "google",
            "data"  =>
            [
                "google1" => 4,
                "google2" => 5,
                "google3" => 6,
            ]
        ],
        [
            "name"  => "gelecekCom",
            "id"    => "gelecekCom",
            "data"  =>
            [
                "gelecek1" => 4,
                "gelecek2" => 5,
                "gelecek3" => 6,
            ]
        ],
    ];
```

I keep it

```
var return = JSON.parse(response);
```

but the data was change

```
id: "instagram", name: "instagram", data: cats1: 4, cats2: 5, cats3: 6
```

but i want to this one

```
id: "instagram", name: "instagram", data: "cats1": 4,"cats2": 5,"cats3": 6
```

i can't find any solution for this one, i'm not good in javascript, is there anyone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Those are both the same thing, JavaScript doesn't care about quotes for keys after its been converted from JSON.

Comment: Hi @Mahir ÇATAL, You used a `highcharts` tag, but your problem does not seem to be related with Highcharts, but with the data. Here you can see an example of required data structure: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

Comment: You have provided the data structure in PHP format. If relevant, please show how you pass that data to the client (JS). If not relevant, please provide the data in JSON format, which is how you would get it in JavaScript.